# Anyone familiar with using Latex within Emacs (Org-mode) - Why indent para works, but not abnormal parskip (memoir class)

Tags: pdftex, emacs, org-mode

Firstly I will come clean and admit that the only real interaction I have with Latex is from within the Org-mode environment of Emacs.

I am trying to learn latex, however I am finding this confusing as most tutorials for latex are not centered in Emacs.

The main source of confusion is the header of org-mode, where I can declare "Latex_HEADER: arbitrary latex command."

In some instances I have success passing commands to this header prefix.
for example

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

which sets no indent for each paragraph.

In other instances I have no luck, such as

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \abnormalparskip{10}
```

however my paragraphs have not changed after the above.

Any guidance on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with org mode. You should postthe generated latex code (if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about `org-mode`. However the following regular LaTeX code works.

```
% orgmodeprob.tex  SE 585974
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\abnormalparskip{10pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\abnormalparskip{10pt}` whereas you said that you used `\abnormalparskip{10}` which produces an error.

[image]

Comment: many thanks for that. I need to pay more attention!